# Getting all PathMatchers from Spray route.

Tags: scala, spray

I have a Spray rotue. For example:

```
val myRoute = (get & path("get_init_data")) { 
    ???
} ~ (post & path("push")) { 
    ???
}
```

Is it possible to extract all paths that are defined in the route? I need to extract paths names and paths methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no: spray routes are just functions from `RequestContext` to `Unit` and thus they are opaque. You are looking for something that is more common in more web-oriented frameworks.